# How to terminate a Cisco WebVPN Smart Tunnel?

Tags: vpn, tunnel, cisco-vpn-client

I am a user, not an admin. I am using a Cisco WebVPN webpage where I can start my Smart Tunnel and then access to internal resources via Remote Desktop. The connection works fine. However the "Logout" button doesn't work on the webpage, so I cannot properly close my Smart Tunnel session. It stays active even if I close IE. This is odd as I cannot connect to "normal" servers via RDP, just to my VPN ones. How can I terminate the Smart Tunnel session? I went through my Windows 10 processes and services, tried to stop and restart several ones, but nothing helped, the connection stayed active. Deleting IE cookies also didn't help. I think I should delete the session cookie from the memory somehow, but I cannot. So I want to stop this application-level interception called Smart Tunnel, but I cannot. The only solution is to log out of Windows and log in again (i.e. stopping explorer.exe), but this is uncomfortable. Do you have any suggestion how can I terminate the Smart Tunnel in my system? Where is this session exactly maintained?

[image]

Comment: Are you on Windows? If you are, do you see an icon added in the traybar when starting the tunnel, and can you right-click it?

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows 10. There is no icon on the Taskbar, it's a Clientless application. Nothing has been installed on my machine, the Smart Tunnel is started in Internet Explorer by invoking a Java Applet. This applet probably intercepts the traffic between my Remote Desktop client and the VPN gateway and makes me able to connect to remote machines. All I want is stop this interception. But I cannot, it keeps running even if I close IE.

Comment: Can you see in *Start > View network connections* a network adapter for the VPN, and what happens if you disable it?

Comment: No adapters are created when I connect. This is a Clientless app, everything is managed from Internet Explorer, so at most DLLs play any role here, but no client applications are installed.

Comment: When the VPN is enabled, do you see anything in *Settings >Network & Internet >Proxy* ? Or in *Start > Internet Options > Connections > LAN settings* under "Proxy server"?

Comment: No, they are all empty. I think Cisco WebVPN technology uses some application level components for the traffic interception, not the standard Proxy thing.

Comment: Do you see a Java application running via Task Manager and can you terminate it? And how do you manage to run IE in Windows 10 (Windows shouldn't let you)?

Comment: No. Java is invoked only when the Tunnel starts, but then closes immediately. So there is no java*.exe in Task Manager and also no coffee cup icon on the Taskbar. I have reverted back from Edge to IE as Smart Tunnel is supported only by IE. Thanks anyway for spending your time on this!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more. My very last idea is to use Windows Sandbox (or a better third party product) to run IE and RDP inside a sandbox that can be easily terminated, while being isolated from the rest of the system.

Comment: One addition: I just realized that starting the Smart Tunnel loads a DLL (csvrelay64.dll) and this DLL runs under explorer.exe. The DLL remains loaded even after closing IE. So unloading the DLL can only be done by restarting explorer.exe (this explains why the Tunnel closes when I log off and log in again). At least I know how to force to close the Tunnel. On the other hand the proper way of closing the Tunnel would be to erase the Session Cookie from the memory, but there is no UI which would make it possible. Apparently a Cisco bug, isn't it?

Comment: I wouldn't know if this is a bug or a "feature", but it's easy enough to write a `.bat` file that restarts Explorer.

Comment: I would call it a bug. There is a logout button on the webpage which worked fine months ago and closed the session. However it doesn't work anymore and I haven't found any way to delete the Session Cookie from the memory. This would be the proper way of terminating the Session, unloading the DLLs by restarting explorer.exe is just a workaorund and also not sure it's a reliable solution. What if the re-loading DLLs uses the previous, still existing Session Cookie? Anyway, thanks for your efforts, I will accept your solution if nobody else lets me know how to delete the Session Cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it might help, here is a `.bat` file that will kill and restart
Explorer:

```
taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
start "" explorer.exe
```

This workaround will at least fix the problem.